# TinyMce javascript/React allow just a single Line

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce

I've been trying to solve a problem for a while now, but I just can't seem to figure it out. I want to use the TinyMCE Rich Text Editor in my application for regular single-line text inputs because I can customize them according to my needs. The issue I'm facing is that it allows multiple lines, and when I reach the end of the field, it automatically creates a line break. However, I want only a single line to be allowed. Any ideas on how I can achieve this? I've already tried a lot. Thanks in advance.

I tried to manipulate the init on many ways

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.